# Spinner Android

Tags: java, android, android-widget

**The code below it works perfect, How I can replace EditText to Spinner?**

I had tried the basic Spinner, it works but became error for multiple Spinner (I need to my project) that I have no idea to make it.

```
   public class TTS_1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText box1, box2, box3;
    TextView txtView;
    Button btnOk;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tts_1);

        txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        box1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt1);
        box2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt2);
        box3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt3);
        btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnOK);

        final String [] arrayQuestion = {"1", "2", "3"};
        final String [] arrayAnswer = new String[3];

        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                arrayAnswer[0] = box1.getText().toString();
                arrayAnswer[1] = box2.getText().toString();
                arrayAnswer[2] = box3.getText().toString();
                if (Arrays.equals(arrayAnswer,arrayQuestion)) {
                    txtView.setText("Arrays is equals");
                }
                else {
                    txtView.setText("Arrays is not equals");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Sorry, it is not an error but just show else statement(the input is correct).

my basic spinner is:

```
final String[] theQuestion2 = {"1", "2", "3"};
    final String [] theNumbers = {" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};

spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, theNumbers);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, theNumbers);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter2);

    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
    ArrayAdapter adapter3 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, theNumbers);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter3);
```

Comment: post the spinner code and show us the error

Comment: You asked for spinner so where is your spinner code and error log ?

Comment: I just edited my question.... thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this
Declare a spinner with some name in your xml file

```
  <Spinner
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
   android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
   android:layout_weight="8"
   android:id="@+id/some"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   />
```

Now in your java declare a array adapter

```
 ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1;
```

Put the following line inside onCreate method

```
 spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.some);
 adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.some, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

Where R.array.some refers to array value in res>strings ,

```
 <string-array name="some">
        <item>Select</item>
        <item>Select1</item>
        <item>Select2</item>
 </string-array>
```

you can also add it using arraylist instead of arrayadapter.
This method helps you Create as many spinners you like

Comment: Thank you, it takes time to me to implement your code.

Comment: The reason your code didnt work because you have declared all the spinners with the same name "Spinner1" try using different name,it will work for sure

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter;
Spinner Id_mSpinner;
```

Put the following line inside onCreate method

```
Id_mSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.some);
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.some, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
Id_mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.